# How to convert a file to UTF-8 in php?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

Is it possible to convert a file into UTF-8 on my end?

If I have an access on the file after the submission with

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
```

**Note:** The user can upload a CSV file with any kind of charset, I usually encounter an **unknown 8-bit** charset.

I try

```
$row = array();
$datas = file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
foreach($datas as $data) {
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');
    $row[] = explode(',', $data);
}
```

But the problem is, this code remove special characters like single quote.

My first question is [htmlspecialchars remove the value inside the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823873/htmlspecialchars-remove-the-value-inside-the-array/46824852?noredirect=1#comment80608968_46824852)

I put it for additional information. Thanks for those who can help!

Comment: Any sample file one can try?

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7980354/1348344

Comment: So the best solution is just to detect if it contains a utf-8?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the question linked by TomášVotruba (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or). The fact that your string comes from a file makes no difference, because actually all the code here does is populate `$data`, which like in the other question is a string in an unknown encoding. It seems I can't close as duplicate while the bounty is open, though.

Comment: checkout the iconv extension for PHP, it has some pretty good mechanisms for converting character encoding, much better than the mb_family of functions...

Answer (score 5):

```
function convert_file_to_utf8($source, $target) {
    $content=file_get_contents($source);
    # detect original encoding
    $original_encoding=mb_detect_encoding($content, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true);
    # now convert
    if ($original_encoding!='UTF-8') {
        $content=mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', $original_encoding);

    }
    $bom=chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191); # use BOM to be on safe side
    file_put_contents($target, $bom.$content);
}
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly for my issue of processing unpredictably formatted CSV's via LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

Answer (score 3):

before you can convert it to utf-8, you need to know what characterset it is.
if you can't figure that out, you can't in any sane way convert it to utf8..
however, an insane way to convert it to utf-8, if the encoding cannot be determined,
is to simply strip any bytes that doesn't happen to be valid in utf-8, you 
might be able to use that as a fallback...

warning, untested code (im suddenly in a hurry), but may look something like this:

```
foreach ( $datas as $data ) {
    $encoding = guess_encoding ( $data );
    if (empty ( $encoding )) {
        // encoding cannot be determined...
        // as a fallback, we simply strip any bytes that isnt valid utf-8...
        // obviously this isn't a reliable conversion scheme.
        // also this could probably be improved
        $data = iconv ( "ASCII", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $text );
    } else {
        $data = mb_convert_encoding ( $data, 'UTF-8', $encoding );
    }
    $row [] = explode ( ',', $data );
}
function guess_encoding(string $str): string {
    $blacklist = array (
            'pass',
            'auto',
            'wchar',
            'byte2be',
            'byte2le',
            'byte4be',
            'byte4le',
            'BASE64',
            'UUENCODE',
            'HTML-ENTITIES',
            '7bit',
            '8bit' 
    );
    $encodings = array_flip ( mb_list_encodings () );
    foreach ( $blacklist as $tmp ) {
        unset ( $encodings [$tmp] );
    }
    $encodings = array_keys ( $encodings );
    $detected = mb_detect_encoding ( $str, $encodings, true );
    return ( string ) $detected;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out.
The example I have used was something I was doing in a test environment, you might need to change the code slightly.

I had a text file with the following data in:

```
test
café
áÁÁÁááá
žžœš¥±
ÆÆÖÖÖasØØ
ß
```

Then I had a form which took a file input in and performed the following code:

```php
function neatify_files(&$files) {
    $tmp = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($_FILES[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]]["name"]); $j++) {
            $tmp[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]][$j]["name"] = $_FILES[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]]["name"][$j];
            $tmp[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]][$j]["type"] = $_FILES[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]]["type"][$j];
            $tmp[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]][$j]["tmp_name"] = $_FILES[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]]["tmp_name"][$j];
            $tmp[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]][$j]["error"] = $_FILES[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]]["error"][$j];
            $tmp[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]][$j]["size"] = $_FILES[array_keys($_FILES)[$i]]["size"][$j];
        }
    }
    return $files = $tmp;
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    neatify_files($_FILES);
    $file = $_FILES["file"][0];

    $handle = fopen($file["tmp_name"], "r");
    while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
        $enc = mb_detect_encoding($line, "UTF-8", true);
        if (strtolower($enc) != "utf-8") {
            echo "<p>" . (iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $line)) . "</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>$line</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The function `neatify_files` is something I wrote to make the `$_FILES` array more logical in its layout.

The form is a standard form that simply `POST`s the data to the server.
*Note: Using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is a security risk, [see here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14585751/3578036).*

When the data is posted I store the file in a variable. Obviously, if you are using the `multiple` attribute your code won't look quite like this.

`$handle` stores the entire contents of the text file, in a read-only format; hence the `"r"` argument.

`$enc` uses the [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) function to detect the encoding (duh).
At first I was having trouble with obtaining the correct encoding. Setting the `encoding_list` to use only UTF-8, and setting `strict` to be true.

If the encoding is UTF-8 then I simply print the line, if it didn't I converted it to UTF-8 using the [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function.

Comment: @OblivionCoder Any chance you could confirm if this answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
function encode_utf8($data)
{
    if ($data === null || $data === '') {
        return $data;
    }
    if (!mb_check_encoding($data, 'UTF-8')) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$content = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$content = encode_utf8($content);

$rows = explode("\n", $content);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the file text into binary data by using the following

```
FUNCTION bin2text($bin_str) 
{ 
    $text_str = ''; 
    $chars = EXPLODE("\n", CHUNK_SPLIT(STR_REPLACE("\n", '', $bin_str), 8)); 
    $_I = COUNT($chars); 
    FOR($i = 0; $i < $_I; $text_str .= CHR(BINDEC($chars[$i])), $i  ); 
    RETURN $text_str; 
} 

FUNCTION text2bin($txt_str) 
{ 
    $len = STRLEN($txt_str); 
    $bin = ''; 
    FOR($i = 0; $i < $len; $i  ) 
    { 
        $bin .= STRLEN(DECBIN(ORD($txt_str[$i]))) < 8 ? STR_PAD(DECBIN(ORD($txt_str[$i])), 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) : DECBIN(ORD($txt_str[$i])); 
    } 
    RETURN $bin; 
}
```

after converting the data into binary you simply change the text to php method **mb_convert_encoding($fileText, "UTF-8");**

Comment: Why are you uppercasing PHP keywords?

Comment: Not an issue, but this is kinda weird. Does this mean you never use editors'  autocompletion and snippets?