# Wordpress with Chinese language inserts garbled characters into .htaccess file causing it to break

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

This was originally posted in Wordpress Bug report & comment, but after going through various tries to resolve the problem, I think it could be an environment issue. This happens in Wordpress 6.3.2 (as on bug report) and 6.4.2 (this is the version I have tested).

Here is the link to the [original bug report & comment](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/59608).

Basically, the problem is: I have a Wordpress site with Language set to zh_TW (Chinese Taiwan). Most of time it works fine, but occasionally I get Server error 500. It seems that Wordpress is adding Chinese UTF-8 comments into the .htaccess, but that comment block is not correctly encoded resulting in garbled characters.

Sample of the broken .htaccess

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
# 在含有 BEGIN Wordpress 及 END Wordpress 標記的這�
�行間的指示詞�
�容為動�
�產生，
# 且應�
有 WordPress 篩選器能進行修改。對這�
�行間任何指示詞�
�容的變更，
# 都會遭到系統覆寫。
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
```

Expected .htaccess should be

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
# 在含有 BEGIN Wordpress 及 END Wordpress 標記的這兩行間的指示詞內容為動態產生，
# 且應僅有 WordPress 篩選器能進行修改。對這兩行間任何指示詞內容的變更，
# 都會遭到系統覆寫。
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
```

This code is added by `wp-admin/includes/misc.php`

After lots of investigation, I have found that only some characters causes the problem. I have tried manually inserting the Chinese character into the misc.php code.

I first tried changing this code:

```
$instructions = sprintf(
        __(
'The directives (lines) between "BEGIN %1$s" and "END %1$s" are
dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.'
        ),
        $marker
    );
```

Changing simply to this below would break the htaccess

```
$instructions = '# 兩';
```

But changing to this below, would NOT

```
$instructions = '# 我';
```

I have checked my php.ini `default_charset = "UTF-8"`, both input_encoding and output_encoding are not set.

Another test case I tried was to manually insert `# 兩` somewhere in the .htaccess. This **also** causes the problem after insert_with_markers is executed. After reading through the code, it seems the code is reading and re-writing the entire file. This seem to indicate to me that the problem occurs when the strings are re-written into .htaccess.

Forcing the code to do `mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8')` on every single line also doesn't seem to make a difference as suggested on [How to convert a file to UTF-8 in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842606/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-php).

I have tried to also force the code to write the UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of the file, but Apache also fail with http 500 upon reading the BOM.

Lastly, I copied out the function, wrote it as a stand-alone php file to execute on the command line in the server environment. This does **NOT **reproduce the problem, and results in a useable .htaccess file. I had to disable switch_to_locale, but this didn't seem to make any difference even if I disabled it in misc.php.

So what is different about executing this code directly on the server vs via CGI. phpinfo did not reveal any difference in default_charset and other encoding values.

Any thoughts on how I can deal with this or what else to look at?

Here is some setting information:

- Server is Linux 4.19.286
- PHP 7.4.33
- exif.encode_unicode = IOS-8859-15
- default_charset = UTF-8